# WPF Toolkit LiveExplorer XAML - Error in Design View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, toolkit

I'm very newbie in XAML and I downloaded Extended WPF Toolkit 2.5 source and all compile fine. But when I open MainWindow.xaml from LiveExplorer Project(Samples Demo), I got an error: "nested types don´t have support":

```
xmlns:samples="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer.Samples;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer"
                            ...
                            ...
       <core:LiveExplorerTreeViewItem Header="PropertyGrid"
                                       ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewSubHeaderStyle}"
                                       SampleType="{x:Type samples:PropertyGrid.Views.PropertyGridView}"
                                       IsSelected="True">
```

> SampleType="{x:Type samples:PropertyGrid.Views.PropertyGridView}"

I have tried with Visual Studio 2015 CE, 2013 & 2012 Express and 2010, and all show me the same errors.

Samples->PropertyGrid->View is a directory structure and not nested properties as others too:
Samples->DataGrid->Views
Samples->ListBox->Views, etc.

I have checked others sources versions and theses codes are the same. Is it normal? Can we make a reference using "folder structure".properties in XAML? Or do we need several xmlns declarations for each one?

```
    xmlns:pgv="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer.Samples.PropertyGrid.Views;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer"
    xmlns:dgv="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer.Samples.DataGrid.Views;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer"
    xmlns:lbv="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer.Samples.ListBox.Views;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer"
    xmlns:clv="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer.Samples.CheckLists.Views;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer"
                          ...
```